# Writing Any Set In Set Builder Form

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can any set be written in set builder notation? If yes, then how to write a set having no proper property like A= {1, 1957379, 23485783} in set builder notation. Kindly explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but perhaps trivially. Just define your property as being one of those numbers:

$P(x) = ``x=1 \textrm{ or }x=1957379\textrm{ or }x=23485783"$

Then $$A=\{ x \mid P(x)\}$$

Comment: What about if $A$ is infinite?

Comment: @JacobMaibach : Then $P(x) = ``x\in A"$, and $A=\{x\mid P(x)\}$. As I said, this is a trivial way of using the notation.

Comment: @MPW Isn't the infinite case (especially uncountably infinite) worth a more careful treatment? Certainly the finite case is trivial, as in the OP's question, but "$P(x) = \textrm'x \in A\textrm'$ and $A = \{x \mid P(x) \}$" seems problematic if you can't actually list out the elements of $A$.

Comment: It depends on what OP means by set builder notation. I always think of that as specifying a property that elements must satisfy, and it sounds like that's what OP is saying. But if you mean to have an explicit list, then you can only every specify finite sets (using "$\cdots$" isn't permitted). It is certainly true that the property I specified is satisfied precisely by the elements of $A$. But this is a chicken-and-egg situation since you have to know $A$ to define the property. Doesn't matter, it is trivially true.

Comment: In one line this would be written as $A = \{x\ |\ x = 1 \vee x = 1957379 \vee x = 23485783\}$ (or is written as $\vee$ and and is written as $\land$)

Comment: What if we use ∧ symbol instead of ∨ ?

Comment: @WaqarAliShah : Then the set is empty. There is no $x$ that simultaneously satisfies $x=x_1$ AND $x=x_2$ if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different numbers. That's why you want "OR", not "AND".

Comment: @MPW, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to express this set in the roster form as it gives us no particular advantage to express it in set builder form.